# Recorrer los valores de un Json almacenado en un campo sql

Tags: php, sql, json

ante todo decir que soy novatísimo en php, estoy aprendiendo con PHP 5.4 en CodeIgniter 2.0.1 y es mi primer día en stackoverflow.

He almacenado un json en una tabla llamada "**tienda**" y tengo los siguientes campos:
-**id**
-**contratos**
-**precio** (aquí esta almacenado mi Json que es **"corbata": "15€"**

Entonces tengo un helper que muesta por defecto unos precios alojados en el, que se llama:

```
$precio = $CI->config->item('precios_tienda');
```

Tengo que sustituir los precios del helper por los de la tabla y estoy intentando esto:
aclarar que $cliente esta definido en otra parte,

Intento primero recorrer el array para saber si existe cliente en $cliente, y despues recorro la $key que es corbata pero no se como representar el valor, estoy perdido.
¿Me podríais recomendar alguna documentación o algo para saber que hacer?,

Un saludo y muchas gracias

```
if ($cliente !=null) {
    $query = "SELECT precio
        FROM tienda
        WHERE cliente = '" . $cliente . "'";

    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->row();

    $array = json_decode($row->precio, true);

    foreach ($array as $key => $name) {
     
        if ($key == 'corbata') {
               
            foreach ($array2 as $value => $valor) {



            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por fín!!! al final he logrado hacelo con esto:

```
    if ($contrato != null) {

      
    $query = "SELECT precio
    FROM tienda
    WHERE cliente = '" . $cliente . "'";

        $query16 = $CI->db->query($query16);

        foreach ($query16->result() as $row) {
            $precios_ng = $row->precio;
            $precios8 = json_decode($precio, true);

            foreach ($precios8 as $key => $value) {
                $precios[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Realmente no entiendo mucho esta solución. En primer lugar, ¿por qué haces un `json_decode`? En segundo lugar, ¿de dónde sale `$precio` en tu contexto? No lo veo definido previamente en ningún lado. Si nos muestras cómo están los datos, poniendo un `var_dump($row);` quizá podemos ayudarte a una mejor solución. Me parece que estás mareando demasiado los datos, convirtiendo y reconvirtiendo, con el uso de memoria que ello puede implicar.

Comment: Hola, en primer lugar perdón por no poner más contexto en la pregunta, soy muy novato en PHP y en la programación en general. El Json_decode lo hago porque en un campo tengo la información almacenada como tal, como elaboro en la primera pregunta, el contexto de precio no puse porque se me olvidó, y creo que al final encontre otra solución distinta, intentaré buscarlo y volverlo a exponer, para que me puedas aconsejar, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.